# Bundling GDAL 3.0.2 with PyInstaller

Tags: gdal, proj, pyinstaller

I'm not sure if this is the right Stack to ask in, but I've been recently trying to bundle the latest wheel of GDAL 3.0.2 x64 downloaded from 
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal 
for python 3.8 (and 3.7) using Pyinstaller version 4.0.dev0+2255bba498 (version 3.5 on python 3.7)
I keep encountering the error:

```
PROJ: proj_as_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
```

This did not occur when using GDAL version 2.4.1 downloaded from the same wheel location as before. This error does not occur when running a standard python environment either in a debugger or as a command line.

I've tried including the proj.db as a hidden import and the whole folder it is contained in as a hidden import without any luck. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, I can include my .spec file for PyInstaller if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding PROJ_LIB (with the path to proj.db folder) to the windows environmental variable. I have also read that another way is to add this line to your code: `os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = '/your/path/to/proj'`